# HTML tag that will display it's contents as a text node

Tags: html, tags

Is there an HTML tag that will display it's contents as a text node?

**Example:**

`<tag><img src="pics/man.jpg"></tag>`

**This should be displayed like the following in a browser:**

```
<tag><img src="pics/man.jpg"></tag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, HTML does provide such a tag. It's `<xmp>...</xmp>`

http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/473699/how_to_display_html_on_a_website_without.html?cat=59

> What's the catch? Not every browser
>   supports xmp. It's a deprecated tag,
>   no longer in the "standard" version of
>   HTML. Some browsers support it, but
>   others don't. If you try to use an xmp
>   tag to display some HTML and a user
>   with an unsupported browser comes to
>   your site, he or she won't be able to
>   see the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. XML and therefore XHTML let  you write the following:

```
<![CDATA[
<tag><img src="pics/man.jpg"></tag>
]]>
```

but HTML does not allow that.

However, replacing all occurrences of `<` with `&lt;` and replacing all occurrences of `&` with `&amp;` should do the trick.

Comment: I do use `XHTML`, but when I pasted your code in the body section of my document it wasn't displayed properly.

Comment: Well, I don't think any browser parses XHTML. They all parse HTML :)

Answer (score -2):

How about using the pre tag?

```
<pre><tag><img src="pics/man.jpg"></tag> </pre>
```